# SDL2 MessageBox button size

Tags: c++, sdl-2

So Im trying to show a messagebox in C++/SDL2 and im doing great but for some reason the buttons are way to small (see screenshot), here is my code:

```
    std::string message = "test";

    SDL_MessageBoxButtonData bd = SDL_MessageBoxButtonData();
    bd.buttonid = 0;
    bd.text = "Exit";
    bd.flags = SDL_MESSAGEBOX_BUTTON_ESCAPEKEY_DEFAULT | SDL_MESSAGEBOX_BUTTON_RETURNKEY_DEFAULT;

    SDL_MessageBoxData md = SDL_MessageBoxData();
    memset(&md, 0, sizeof(md)); // initialize to 0
    md.buttons = &bd;
    md.numbuttons = 1;
    md.flags = SDL_MESSAGEBOX_ERROR;
    md.title = "Pulse Crash";
    md.window = nullptr;
    md.message = message.c_str();

    int bid = 0;
    SDL_ShowMessageBox(&md, &bid);

    exit(0);
```

is there anything i can do about this, like make them bigger or am I going to have to live with this?

Im on Windows 10 Pro if that matters.

[screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gMlab.png)

I tried googling but didnt find anyone with the same problem there also was no issue over this on SDL's github.

EDIT: on message boxes with longer messages the buttons stay the same size thus looking very small in comparison